# What is at x- and y-axis on the Normal Probability Plot and how to calculate it?

Tags: normal-distribution, qq-plot, z-score

So we have normal scores aka rankings on the x-axis, called theoretical quantiles and on the y we have the sample quantiles, but how do we calculate them, if we assume that the data derives from a normal distribution?

If the result of plot will more or less look like a linear line, then our sample derives from the normal distributed population, right?